Smallest subalgebra which commutant is trivial.
Conventions
Let $k$ be a field, $M_n(k)$ be the unitary algebra of square matrices and $T_n(k)$ its sub-algebra (also unitary) of upper-triangular matrices and $N_n(k)$ its sub-vector space of nilpotent matrices. We denote for any algebra $\mathcal A$ its center
$$Z (\mathcal A) := \{a \in \mathcal A \mid [a,\mathcal A] = 0\}$$
And for any sub-algebra $\mathcal B \subset \mathcal A$ we denote its commutant
$$\mathcal C (\mathcal B) := \{ a \in \mathcal A \mid [a,\mathcal B ] = 0\}$$
It is clearly a sub-algebra of $\mathcal A$, but it is not necessarily commutative.
One can see that using the bicommutant theorem that states for any endomorphism $u$ we have $\mathcal C \mathcal C (u) = k[u]$ and we have $k[u] \subset \mathcal C (u) $ but the inclusion is not in general an equality.

Question
An easy result is $Z(M_n(k)) = \mathcal C(T_n(k)) = Z(T_n(k)) = k \cdot I_n$ since they both contain all the transvections (indeed linear "homotéties" which are linear maps which stabilise all lines are necessary of the form $\lambda\cdot I_n$).
Seeing this I wondered if any smaller (in dimension) subalgebra $\mathcal A \subset M_n(k)$ would also have a trivial commutant. To study this, I checked the two proofs I knew for $Z(M_n(k)) = k \cdot I_n$:

$M_n(k)$ contains all the transvections $I_n + \lambda E_{i,j}$ with $i<j$ thus any element of the commutant must stabilise all lines and is necessary of the form $\mu \cdot I_n$.
$M_n(k)$ contains all the $E_{i,j}$ and with some elementary matrices product, we recall $A \in \mathcal C (M_n(k)) \iff a_{1,1} = \cdots = a_{n,n}$ and $a_{i,j} = 0$ for $i\neq j$.

Both of these are centered around the $E_{i,j}$ and I figured that if $\mathcal B$ were to be small, we should have for $U \in \mathcal B$ $\deg \Pi_U$ (the minimal polynomial) smallest possible since commuting with $U$ implies commuting with $k[U]$ and $k [U] \subset \mathcal B$.
This means we should aim for $\min_{b \in \mathcal B} \deg \Pi_b = 2$ if possible.
Another remark on the minimal polynomial is that it should have $0$ as one of its roots, otherwise $k \cdot \langle u \rangle$ would be containing the identity, which is useless in our journey to reduce the size of the commutant.
So far, I found the smallest algebra (it is only one example) to verify this to be
$$\mathcal B = k\cdot \langle E_{1,1}, E_{1,2} ,\dots, E_{1,n}\rangle \subset T_n(k)$$
The only non-trivial multiplications are the $E_{1,1} E_{1,i} = E_{1,i}$ so it has dimension $n$.
It has a unit on the left but not on the right so it is not nilpotent. And all its elements are "idempotent-like" (which means $x^2 \in k \cdot x$) since if we have $B = \lambda E_{1,1} + N$ with $n \in k[E_{1,j},j>1] \subset N_n(k)$, we have
$$B^2 = \lambda^2 E_{1,1}^2 + \lambda E_{1,1} n + \lambda n E_{1,1} + n^2 = \lambda^2 E_{1,1} + \lambda  n = \lambda(\lambda E_{1,1} + n) = \lambda B.$$
This means the minimal polynomial of $B \neq 0$ is $X(X - \langle E_{1,1}, B \rangle)$.
So for $\mathcal A$ an unitary algebra, we denote
$$N(\mathcal A) : = \min \{ \dim \mathcal B \mid \mathcal B \, \text{is a subalgebra of}\, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal C (\mathcal B) = k \cdot 1\} $$
and
$$N_u(\mathcal A) : = \min \{ \dim \mathcal B \mid \mathcal B \, \text{is a unitary subalgebra of}\, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal C (\mathcal B) = k \cdot 1\} $$
Here is my question:
Do we know $N(M_n(k)), \, N(T_n(k)), \, N_u(M_n(k))$ and $N(T_n(k))$? If so do we have $N(M_n(k)) = N(T_n(k)) = n$? The first equality could be shown if we had guarantee this algebra would be solvable as a Lie algebra. What about the unitary case? Do we have $N_u(\mathcal A) = N(\mathcal A) + 1$?
I guess if we had some kind of result like if $A \notin k \cdot I_n$, $\dim \mathcal C(A) \leq n$ but this must not be true if we have repeated eigenvalues alongside with non-cyclic parts we could have a bigger commutant.
My work
After figuring working with the $E_{i,j}$ was the most reasonable solution, since they fit all the requirements I wanted and that up to isomorphism we could probably get back to them. Another nice thing is that they are idempotents and the multiplication formula is quite easy: $E_{i,j} E_{k,l} = \delta_j^k E_{i,l}$.
How do they work on coefficients?

On diagonal coefficients, we gave $E_{i,j}A = AE_{i,j} \implies a_{i,i} = a_{j,j}$.
On non-diagonal coefficients we have $E_{i,j}A = AE_{i,j} \implies a_{j,k} = 0 = a_{l,i}$ for $k \neq j$ and $l \neq i$.

On the first point, we need to ensure that we can always find a path $k_0 \to k_1 \to \cdots \to k_m = 1$ where $(k_j,k_{j+1})$ or $(k_{j+1},k_i)$ is present in the family of couples (so at least $n-1$ couples are needed) to have a constant diagonal. On the second it gives results on the cross which center is $(j,i)$ so we have to "place these crosses" in an efficient way, this means you need at least $n$ elements at least to do so.
Combining these, I found my example (which is definitely not unique, e.g. It should be stable by permutation change of base). Here is a more graphic representation of $\mathcal B$:
$$\mathcal B = \begin{pmatrix}
* & * & \cdots & *\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots && \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Helpful remarks:
Th dimension of the commutant does not depend on the field, so we might as well work in a splitting closed field, then If you have an endomorphism $u$ with a Jordan decomposition with blocks $J(k_1,\lambda_1), \dots J(k_r,\lambda_r)$ where all the couples are distinct and with exactly $m_j$ blocs of the form $J(k_j,\lambda_j)$, you know that
$$\dim \mathcal C (u) \ge \sum_{j=1}^r (\dim \mathcal C (J(k_j,\lambda_j)))\cdot {m_j^2} =  \sum_{j=1}^r k_j \cdot {m_j^2}$$
since $J$ is cyclic and any commutant endomorphisms preserves kernels of polynomials of $u$.
And if $u$ is diagonalisable with eigenvalues $\lambda \in \operatorname{Sp}(u)$ whith multiplicities $m(\lambda)$, its commutant is constituted of exactly all the endomorphisms stabilising the eigenspaces, thus
$$\dim \mathcal C(u) = \dim \bigoplus_{\lambda \in \operatorname{Sp}(u)} \mathcal L(E_\lambda) = \sum_{\lambda \in \operatorname{Sp}(u)} m(\lambda)^2.$$
So we might as well have semi-simple endomorphisms in order to limit the unnecessary big commutant.
